# Дефект в отображении репутации в сводке

Tags: дефект, репутация, профиль-участника

Получил вознаграждение, но мой ответ *не принят*, но он отображется на вкладке "Активность" (summary) будто он принят.

[image: Summary bug]

При этом он верно отображается во вкладке "Репутация" (reputation):

[image: Reputation tab]

Сам [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/606754/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/609395#609395), и скриншот (вдруг что-то поменяется):

[image: Non-accepted answer with bounty]

Comment: ["Всё украдено до нас"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164176/339911).